# Rendering Facebook feed using jQuery and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, facebook

I have this JSON response from a facebook.php service file I have.

```
var feeds = {
    "data": [{
        "message": "Over five million faulty appliances were made and sold in the UK.",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T13:20:10+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440949067217"
    }, {
        "message": "#Trubama \ud83c\udf7b",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T12:52:21+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440904607217"
    }, {
        "message": "President Obama says he is not responsible for Donald J. Trump.",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T12:30:00+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440873197217"
    }, {
        "message": "Hold nerve and vote for freedom, Boris Johnson urges Vote Leave campaigners ahead of #EUref bbc.in\/1SFiXES",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T12:00:48+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440832362217"
    }, {
        "message": "He's gone.",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T11:41:49+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440802817217"
    }, {
        "message": "See what #Eclipse2016 looked like from space. As seen by DSCOVR Earth observation satellite. bbc.in\/1XhyHNh",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T11:36:19+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440793632217"
    }, {
        "story": "BBC News shared a link.",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T11:20:01+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440775692217"
    }, {
        "message": "Today BBC World News Turns 25 and a lot has happened in that time! Here's a look back at some of the biggest stories we've covered. Discover more: bbc.in\/24UwxsL #BBCWorldNews25 \ud83c\udf89",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T11:01:15+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440745882217"
    }, {
        "message": "\"Infrastructure is recovering, hearts are not.\"",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T10:37:50+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440708402217"
    }, {
        "message": "(We knew it!)",
        "created_time": "2016-03-11T10:08:24+0000",
        "id": "228735667216_10153440662727217"
    }],
    "paging": {
        "previous": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.5\/228735667216\/feed?limit=10&format=json&since=1457702410&access_token=1708206316123547|XpvdELB3OfY5-kn0LOqh7W23MNU&__paging_token=enc_AdCuzeFl4GuOOkLutF6XEcSqxdA5DLhLSUPBvtUCARGNi7WzUT2imIGgCZA8ewnL2qtcs7PXzDz0ngpGyYz2upZBZAysWiR0ZAAlYGW9uFblXnntyAZDZD&__previous=1",
        "next": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.5\/228735667216\/feed?limit=10&format=json&access_token=1708206316123547|XpvdELB3OfY5-kn0LOqh7W23MNU&until=1457690904&__paging_token=enc_AdCRjMyHpRV4xiZBxFbyRQSR1iBqnmSS0653mnjpAJ7ZBX3aJXmriSS767FKZAr7ixs01wVy9vZBcOMzqovWcsB7zg2TaYEGL2uKACE0ib4qVC84eAZDZD"
    }
};
```

And here is my script. I thought it would be a simple one but it seems everything I try just doesn't work. Could you see what the problem is?

```
<div id="facebook-feed"> </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = "";
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/Labs/Facebook/facebook.php", function(feeds){
        for(var i=0; i<feeds.length; i++) {
            var message = feeds[i].data.message;
            var id = feeds[i].data.id;
            var date = feeds[i].data.created_time;

            html += "<h2>" + message + "</h2>";
            html += "<p>" + date + "</p>";
            html += "<a href='http://facebook.com/" + id + "'>" + "View more" + "</a>";
        }
    });
    $("#facebook-feed").append(html);
});
```

Comment: please be more specific than "it doesn´t work"

Comment: same comments rather than helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through the `feeds` variable, yet that's an object. You need to instead loop through the `feeds.data` array. You also need to `append()` the concatenated HTML string *inside* the callback of `$.getJSON` as it's asynchronous. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/Labs/Facebook/facebook.php", function(feeds) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < feeds.data.length; i++) {
        var message = feeds.data[i].message;
        var id = feeds.data[i].id;
        var date = feeds.data[i].created_time;

        html += "<h2>" + message + "</h2>";
        html += "<p>" + date + "</p>";
        html += "<a href='http://facebook.com/" + id + "'>" + "View more" + "</a>";
    }
    $("#facebook-feed").append(html);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1j9L2Lh2/2)

Comment: Ahh dude you're totally right. Sorry, slow brain on a Friday. Both the placement of the `[i]` and `append(html)` are silly errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will accept as correct when time passes.